# Discord Bot generates error:"message is not defined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Well, I was trying to create an embed for my bot (aka Jarvis) and when I started it it showed the following error: Unable to execute task command.js: ReferenceError: message is not defined

I've done everything, tried to change the command using a base created by other people on sites affiliated with Discord and ended up not finding a solution.

````
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("This is your title, it can hold 256 characters")
  .setAuthor("Author Name", "https://i.imgur.com/lm8s41J.png")
  .setColor(0x00AE86)
  .setDescription("This is the main body of text, it can hold 2048 characters.")
  .setFooter("This is the footer text, it can hold 2048 characters", "http://i.imgur.com/w1vhFSR.png")
  .setImage("http://i.imgur.com/yVpymuV.png")
  .setThumbnail("http://i.imgur.com/p2qNFag.png")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setURL("https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/indev/class/RichEmbed")
  .addField("This is a field title, it can hold 256 characters",
    "This is a field value, it can hold 1024 characters.")
  .addField("Inline Field", "They can also be inline.", true)
  .addBlankField(true)
  .addField("Inline Field 3", "You can have a maximum of 25 fields.", true);

  message.channel.send({embed});```
````

Comment: Is this code block executed inside a message listener? my guess is that it isn't, or you have named the message variable different to it's normal use

Comment: Could you try to refine my code to fit this pattern that was quoted?

Comment: i can't help without seeing the rest of your code. The only issue with the code you have added (as far as i can immediately see), is the `message.channel.send()` which can only be done inside of a message listener context, or passed to a function from there. You need to make sure that your code knows what message is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the `onMessage` listener.

try this code:

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login(<token>);
client.on(`message`, function (message) {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("This is your title, it can hold 256 characters");
      //Reducted the rest of the (.setColor, .setFooter, etc) to save space
    message.channel.send({embed});
});
```

Assuming you know where to get a `<token>` this code here should be exactly what you need.